# Mage log printing any variable/string 2 times

Tags: controllers, log

I am facing very strange problem if i using mage log function in controllers file to print any string/varable/array it prints 2 times in log file

```
Mage::log('string', null, 'mylogfile.log');
Mage::log('$vaiable', null, 'mylogfile.log');
Mage::log('$array', null, 'mylogfile.log');
```

i don't have any idea about this & i also search internet but no appropriate result.
can any help me why this is happening 
because of this i am getting problem in debugging.

Comment: Please add the code context.

Answer (score 0):

See the apache log: if you put at the beginning

```
Mage::log("DEBUG test controller init");
```

and at the end a

```
Mage::log("DEBUG test controller end");
```

Do you see them called twice? That would mean that the controller is called twice.

Now, what file are you playing with?